# Keras variational autoencoder example - usage of latent input

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

I'm new to Keras, and have been struggling with understanding the usage of the variable `z`  in the variational autoencoder example in their official [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py). I don't understand why `z` is not being used instead of the variable `latent_inputs`. I ran the code and it seems to work, but I don't understand if `z` is being used behind the scenes and what is the mechanism in Keras that is responsible for it.
Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
# VAE model = encoder + decoder
# build encoder model
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
x = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(inputs)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(x)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(x)

# use reparameterization trick to push the sampling out as input
# note that "output_shape" isn't necessary with the TensorFlow backend
z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])

# instantiate encoder model
encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')
encoder.summary()
plot_model(encoder, to_file='vae_mlp_encoder.png', show_shapes=True)

# build decoder model
latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
x = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
outputs = Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# instantiate decoder model
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
decoder.summary()
plot_model(decoder, to_file='vae_mlp_decoder.png', show_shapes=True)

# instantiate VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `encoder` is defined as a model that takes inputs `inputs` and gives outputs `[z_mean, z_log_var, z]`. You then define your decoder separately to take some input, here called `latent_inputs`, and output `outputs`. Finally, your overall model is defined in the line that states:

```
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
```

This means you are going to run `encoder` on your `inputs`, which yields `[z_mean, z_log_var, z]`, and then the third element of that (call it `result[2]`) gets passed in as the input argument to `decoder`. In other words, when you implement your network, you are setting `latent_inputs` equal to the third output of your encoder, or `[z_mean, z_log_var, z][2] = z`. You could view it as (probably not valid code):

```
encoder_outputs = encoder(inputs)  # [z_mean, z_log_var, z]
outputs = decoder(latent_inputs=encoder_outputs[2])  # latent_inputs = z
```

Comment: last line `outputs = decoder(encoder_outputs[2])` -- The VAE is only taking `z` as input, leaving `z_mean` and `z_log_var` ignored.

Answer (score 1):

They are just defining separately the encoder and decoder, so that they can be used individually:

- Given some `inputs`, `encoder` computes their latent vectors / lower representations `z_mean, z_log_var, z` (you could use the `encoder` by itself e.g. to store those lower-dimensional representations, or for easier comparison).
- Given such a lower-dimensional representation `latent_inputs`, `decoder` returns the decoded information `outputs` (e.g. if you need to reuse the stored lower representations).

To train/use the complete VAE, both operation can just be chained the way they are actually doing: `outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])` (`latent_inputs` of `decoder` receiving the `z` output of `encoder`).